# ASP.NET Datepicker validation fails to fire when enter a space string

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, datepicker

I'm experiencing weird issue with validation. My datepicker won't fire validation if I enter a space string. The validation works fine with other invalid inputs. Can anyone help me on this?

The custom vilidator I'm taking about is called "date_validate". The first custom validation in below code

ctldatetextbox.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="XXX.WebForms.UI.ctlDateTextbox" Codebehind="ctlDateTextbox.ascx.vb" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="abcv" Namespace="XXX.WebForms.UI.CustomValidators" Assembly="XXX.WebForms.UI" %>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" MaxLength="11" Columns="11" CssClass="datepicker"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Literal ID="ltFormatScript" runat="server" />

<abcv:RequiredPlaceHolderTextboxValidator ID="reqDate" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDate" ErrorMessage="Date is required"
    CssClass="error" Display="Dynamic">&nbsp;</abcv:RequiredPlaceHolderTextboxValidator>

<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="cvDateTextBox" ControlToValidate="txtDate" ClientValidationFunction="date_validate"
    Display="Dynamic" CssClass="error" ErrorMessage="Date is not valid">&nbsp;</asp:CustomValidator>

<asp:CustomValidator ID="custValidation" ControlToValidate="txtDate" OnServerValidate="custValidation_ServerValidate"
    Display="Dynamic" CssClass="error" Enabled="false" runat="server">&nbsp;</asp:CustomValidator>
```

core.js

```
function date_validate(sender, args) {
if (RequiredPlaceHolderTextBoxEvaluateIsValid(sender)) {
    var dtDate = Date.parse(args.Value);
    args.IsValid = (dtDate !== null && dtDate !== 'NaN');
}
```

}

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CustomValidator has a `ValidateEmptyText` property. When set to true the Validator will trigger validate an emty textbox. And that includes a space.

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ValidateEmptyText="true" ID="cvDateTextBox" 
    ControlToValidate="txtDate" ClientValidationFunction="date_validate" Display="Dynamic"
    CssClass="error" ErrorMessage="Date is not valid">&nbsp;</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Comment: Thank you! the ValidateEmptyText solved my issue! :)